# Java add a string in inner list of an array

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array, 2d

Im trying to add string values inside a 2D list.  Was able to add the 1st layer using this:

```
List<List<String>> twodaray = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    List<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();


   for ( int i = 0, m = 1; i < attribteList.size(); i = i+2, m = m+2) {
       String attributeName = attribteList.get(i);
       x.add(attributeName);
   }
   twodaray.add(x);

   for(List<String> ls : twodaray) {
       System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(ls.toArray()));
   }
```

Was wondering how can I access the inner layer of the ArrayList like print it out (sysout) or even adding values to it?  Something like this.

```
    for(List<String> ls : twodaray) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(ls.toArray()));
        for(List<List<String>> ls2d : ls) {
           if (ls = something) {
               ls2d.add(something);
           }
        }
    }
```

Kinda new to using this 2 dimensional list and any help is greatly appreciated. ty...

Comment: Have you tried just `twodarray.toString()`?

Comment: Tried this for(List<String> ls2d : ls) but eclipse error. keeps asking me to change ls2d to string for(String ls2d : ls)

Comment: For that part, Ricky's answer below is close (one layer of `List<>` needs to be taken off). You're supposed to be getting closer to `String`, not further away from it!

Comment: For the printing to `stdout`, though, just doing `twodarray.toString()` should work (no for-loops or anything).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not apparent what exactly you're trying to do, but, this code is close other than a couple of mistakes (= should be .equals(), and the inner and outer foreach loops were somewhat mixed up ):

```
List<String> a = new List<String>();
a.add("Hello");

List<String> b = new List<String>();
b.add("World");

List<List<String>> ls = new List<List<String>>();
ls.add(a);
ls.add(b);

//The outer part (ie. one List of a List of strings
for(List<String> ls : twodaray) {

    //The inner part (ie. one string for each list of strings)
    for(String str : ls) {

       //Check two things for equality (.equals() for strings)
       if (str.equals("Hello")) {
           //Adding "something" to the list (that str is in);
           ls.add("something");
       }
    }
}
```

This question is pretty similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Comment: If I recall my Java correctly, shouldn't there be one less layer of `List<>` in the for-loop declaration? (`List<String> ls` instead of `List<List<String>> ls`)

Comment: @saiarcot895 sorry, you're absolutely right. I was mistaken, and will edit accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like this.

```
for(List<String> ls : twodray) { // twodaray is a List<List<String>>
        System.out.println(ls); // Yes you can simple sysout
        for(String str : ls) { // ls is a List<String>
           if (str.equals("something")) {
               // do something.
           }
        }
    }
```

I think its better to understand the structure of this 2D ArrayList. The 2D ArrayList's elements are 1D ArrayLists. 1D ArrayList's elements are the Strings.

[image]

If you are modifying the same arrayList (specially removes values) while reading it better to use [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html).